# List comprehension to loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

So I have created a working list comprehension, however, to make it easier for some students just learning Python, I would like to get some help with make this comprehension into a loop. I have a list that has several elements of lists, and I want to create a new_list with just element 0 from old_list, the following code works fine.

```
old_list = [['12', '24'],['8', '16'],['4','8']]
new_list = []
new_list = [i[0] for i in old_list]
print(new_list)

output:['12', '8', '4']
```

But, I would like to make this into a for loop and I have tried so many different ways, so could someone please explain how to do this.

I have tried:

```
for i in old_list[0]:
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

And so much more, but still, I can't really understand how to do this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension loops through each list element which is a list and takes only value at index 0. What you tried is to loop through all the first list values at take them all. The correct way is to loop through the main list and take the first value from each list.

```
new_list = []
for value in old_list:
    new_list.append(value[0])
print(new_list)
```

Comment: can you also explain what you changed and why?

Comment: Thank you, this worked and I thought I did this, but now I see that I did miss to put the element within the value, a big thank you!!